# Buliding libaffa: running make says Nothing to be done for 'all'

Tags: compiling, make, libraries

I'm trying to compile the library [libaffa](http://www.nongnu.org/libaffa/), with the following procedure:

```
sudo ./configure -> OK
sudo make && make install -> "Nothing to be done for 'all' "
```

How do I fix this? I run Linux Mint.

News :

```
>> ./configure -> **OK** 

>> autoreconf ->

src/Makefile.am: error: required file './depcomp' not found
src/Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'depcomp'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
automake --add-missing -> src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'


>> autoreconf -> OK


>> make ->

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6/src'
cd .. \
      && CONFIG_FILES=src/Makefile CONFIG_HEADERS= /bin/bash ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/plus91/Scrivania/libaffa-0.9.6'
```

NEWS : Problem Solved

Comment: first - you need sudo only for `sudo make install` and dont need it for other two. Start with that ) `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Is there a `README`, `INSTALL`, or `COMPILING` file that provides detailed instructions?

Comment: @DopeGhoti There's a documentation that says to run the classic triad `./configure` then `make` then `make install`. While doing `sudo make` instead of just `make` could cause permission problems later on, it wouldn't cause `make` to think nothing needs to be done.

Comment: This package wants an old version of `automake`. I tried running `autoreconf` then `automake --add-missing` then `autoreconf` again then `./configure` and `make`, but ran into libtool bugs and gave up.

Comment: And `sudo make && make install` would run `make` as sudo but not `make install` ... The sudo does not survive the `&&` so to speak .

Comment: It *seems* to build on my Ubuntu 14.04 box by following @Gilles instructions except between the `./configure` and `make` steps, replace the generated libtool script with the system libtool using `ln -sf /usr/bin/libtool ./libtool` (the second `autoreconf` is possibly not required).

Comment: have failed to resolve  :( You are able to compile ad install it ? @steeldriver

Comment: @DopeGhoti INSTALL

Comment: @Gilles have failed to resolve :(

Comment: @plus91 please [edit] your question to include the steps you are now following, and the exact errors that occur

Comment: @steeldriver post updated, thx ;)

Comment: You don't seem to have followed the order of operations described in the comments (`autoreconf`, then `automake --add-missing`, then `./configure` then `make`; overwriting `libtool` before running `make` if you get libtool errors). Nevertheless, your `make` command seems to have completed without errors - so did it produce the libraries (look in the `src/.libs` directory)?

Comment: @steeldriver I followed the steps you indicated , but I get the same message . if I try to compile one of the example code : 
g++ -laa example1.cpp -o example,
i get : 
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -laa
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for you help, I solved the problem of compiling ;)

Comment: FYI the library appears to be called `libaffa` not `libaa`: also g++ now enforces library link order by default, so you'd need to use `g++ example1.cpp -laffa -o example`. You may need to add `#include <cstdlib>` to `example1.cpp`

Comment: @steeldriver   I solved in this way :D, thx ;)